# Open another URL on same InAppBrowser instance

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I use PhoneGap InAppBrowser to open a URL. After an event is triggered I use a Javascript function to show a barcode scanner on the top. The barcode scanner then opens another URL to the same (_self) InAppBrowser instance. Problem is that, if I login on the before scanning on that URL, the session does not appear to work after scanning, which means that I have to log in again. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand, can you maybe provide some code or something? Where are you logging into? Are you saying that logging into some website and then using the barcode scanner means it wont work, but if you don't log in, the barcode scanner does?

Comment: My apologies, if I have not been specific. What I mean is say, open the inappbrowser, show and log in to my webapp, then open a scanner window (phonegap barcode scanner), scan something and go back to the webapp on the location that the scanner showed. It works, only that I lose the login and have to login again. Hope, that make sense? It seems like even if I use _self or _blank to open the inappbrowser instance it does not make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the var in a place that is accessible by your method that re-loads the InAppBroswer.

then use

```
browserVar.show();
browserVar.location = 'new location';
```

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#show

Comment: Actually that is pretty much how I solved it some time ago, but never posted the answer.